# How to use json for checkbox event in mvc?

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc

I am using json for displaying checkbox. I want checked checkbox event get data to control. 
I had used this code and encountered an error

[image]

View

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1000" name="HTML" id="GetAccess"  class="box"> 

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#GetAccess").change(function () {
        alert('asa')
        var newValue = true//$(this).checkbox;
        alert(newValue)
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "@(Url.Action(MVC.BaseAdmin.LabAccess.ActionNames.LabAccesscheck, MVC.BaseAdmin.LabAccess.Name))",
            data: newValue,
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual JsonResult LabAccesscheck(int newValue)
{
    Int16 ID = Convert.ToInt16(TempData["id"].ToString());
    TempData["fulname"] = _UserService.getfullname(ID);

    string type = string.Empty;
    IList<P_User_Get_Lab_Access_List_Result> selected = _ILabAccess.GetDataTablebyUser(ID, "Userid");
    //  return (PartialView(MVC.BaseAdmin.LabAccess.Views._ListbyUser, selected));

    return Json(PartialView(MVC.BaseAdmin.LabAccess.Views._ListbyUser, selected), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#GetAccess").change(function () {
        alert('asa')
        var newValue = true;//$(this).checkbox;
        alert(newValue)
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           url: "/LabAccess/LabAccesscheck",
            data: { newValue: newValue) ,
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I try to resolved your error which specify.                                       What is given error??

Comment: i use The above code but see error: $(function () {
           
         $.ajax({
             cache: false,
             type: "GET",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             url: "/LabAccess/LabAccesscheck",
             data: { newValue: newValue} ,
         success: function (data) {
NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:2020/BaseAdmin/LabAccess/LabAccesscheck?newValue=true&_=1434209556011"

Comment: I have used your code and debug with firbug  but not fount page error 500 internral: ia sorry.. I do not understand exactly what you want?

Comment: iam have debug see this error: Invalid JSON primitive: newValue.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: newValue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It will satisfy your query.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery check / uncheck a check box example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>jQuery check / uncheck a check box example</h1>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#isCheck").click(function () {

    alert($('input:checkbox[name=checkme]').is(':checked'));

    });

    $("#checkIt").click(function () {

    $('input:checkbox[name=checkme]').attr('checked',true);

    });

    $("#UnCheckIt").click(function () {

    $('input:checkbox[name=checkme]').attr('checked',false);

    }); 

  });
</script>
</head><body>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkme">Check Me</input>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<input type='button' value='Is Check' id='isCheck'>
<input type='button' value='Check It' id='checkIt'>
<input type='button' value='UnCheck It' id='UnCheckIt'>

</body>
</html>
```